# Type casting Error

Tags: string, go, int

I am trying to follow the tutorial here : https://goethereumbook.org/block-query/

In his code , he calls the `header` and then hard codes it into `blockNumber`.

```
 header, err := client.HeaderByNumber(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(header.Number.String()) // 5671744

    blockNumber := big.NewInt(5671744)
```

I have attempted to improve on this and converted the string to int64.

```
header, err := client.HeaderByNumber(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(header.Number.String())

    var stringBlockNumber = header.Number.String()

    int64BlockNumber, err := strconv.ParseInt(stringBlockNumber, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    blockNumber := big.NewInt(int64BlockNumber)

    block, err := client.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), blockNumber)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

This works until in try to add the following line:

```
fmt.Println(block.Number.Uint64())
```

I get the following error in the terminal :

> ./queryBlock.go:41:26: block.Number.Uint64 undefined (type func()
>   *big.Int has no field or method Uint64)

I would appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: Try `fmt.Println(block.Number().Uint64())`. It seems `block.Number` is a func that returns a `*big.Int` instead of `*big.Int` itself.

Comment: Worked! Can you please add it with an explanation so I can accept it, and others can learn from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the block by number through `client.BlockByNumber`, block is of type `Block` from `/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types`.

`Number` of `Block` is a [method](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types#Block.Number), which returns a `*big.Int` instead of being a field of that type. So To retrieve the number, you should call the method, i.e, `block.Number()`.